# Py2Exe - can't find modules

Tags: python, py2exe, setup.py

I want to create an exe file using `Py2exe` module. The problem is that the exe file says that there is not `os` module. I've put it into `includes` in `setup.py` file so it should work.

Here is the error after run `main.exe` created by `Py2Exe`

```
    import linecache
ImportError: No module named linecache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
```

And here is my `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

    setup(console=["main.py"],options = {
              "py2exe":{
                  "includes": ["os","linecache"]
                  }
              },)
```

Comment: any news about your question?

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you want to [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632845/relative-import-error-with-py2exe/34772426#34772426) packages, you should use the option `packages` and not  `includes`. The first one imports `libraries`, the second `modules.py`.This should work now:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

    setup(console=["main.py"], 
         options = {
              "py2exe":{
                  "packages": ["os","linecache"]
                  }
              })
```