# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses' when trying to use curses in py2exe

Tags: python-3.x, windows, py2exe, python-curses

my python code I'm trying to run:

```
import curses, random
def main(stdscr):
 stdscr.clear()
 for i in range(0, 21):
  stdscr.addstr(i, 0, f'count {i+1}, and rand value {random.randint(0, 100)}')
 stdscr.refresh()
 stdscr.getkey()
curses.wrapper(main)
print("ngos")
```

then I use this for py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=[{"script":"main.py"}], options = {"py2exe":{"packages": ["curses",]}})
```

but when I try and run the exe I get this from the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "curses\__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

I'm using win10 x64

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Py2Exe - can't find modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250217/py2exe-cant-find-modules)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250217/py2exe-cant-find-modules

Comment: no it doesn't help it still says "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "curses\__init__.pyc", line 13, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
"
and  i added "options = {
    "py2exe":{
        "packages": ["curses",]
        }
    }"
and i still get the error